# Update badge without alert when app is open

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10

I'm trying to update the badge value remotely via a push notification.
Everything works fine but when the app is open I get an empty alert (containing my app name and a close button).

I read about [silent notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) in apple's documentation but it seems that even with specifying content-available : 1 in the notification payload, the payload must not contain badge for the notification to be silent.

Is updating the badge without receiving an alert possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a silent push notification, then you cannot include the `badge` key in the `aps` dictionary, so you can't update the badge directly with a silent push.

You *can* include your own keys and values in the `aps` dictionary and this dictionary is available in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` `UIApplicationDelegate` function.

In this function you can extract your own "badge" key from the `aps` dictionary and use this to update the badge number directly using the `UIApplication` property [`applicationIconBadgeNumber`][1]

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = someValue
```

Something like:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let badgeNumberStr = userInfo["myBadge"] as? String {
        if let badgeNumber = Int(badgeNumberStr) {
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I would also like the badge to update its value when a server side action is performed.

Comment: Thanks I understand this solution and will propably end up using it. Just to clarify the default ios behaviour, if a badge value is set in the aps dictionary an alert will be shown no matter what when the app is open ?

Comment: I think that nothing should be displayed when your app is in the foreground; check you haven't got code in your app delegate to present a local notification

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. I didn't mention I was using OneSignal as a push notification provider and their sdk was causing the undesired comportment. Thanks for your time.